# Cloud function on GCP: no exit log

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a google cloud function triggered by a topic pubsub.

Most of the times, everything works fine like this:

```
2021-11-06 15:12:38.830 GMT vote_stage oga5hymuzx4p Function execution started
2021-11-06 15:13:45.392 GMT vote_stage oga5hymuzx4p Function execution took 66563 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
```

But unfortunately, once in twenty, i can only see this:

```
2021-11-06 15:08:45.139 GMT vote_stage rvfnd4wo5nwd Function execution started
```

How is this possible that there is no exit log ?

Below, the code of the function:

```
def vote_stage(event, context):
    assert context == context
    call_datetime = reusable.time.get_now()
    game_id = event['attributes']['game_id']
    logger.info(f'start, game_id={game_id}')
    game = build_game(game_id)
    resp = ut.exceptions.ExceptionsHandler(game).handle_vote_stage_exceptions()
    if resp:
        logger.info(f'exception, game_id={game_id}')
        return resp
    game.dict['vote_stage_last_trigger'] = reusable.time.get_now()
    ut.firestore.FirestoreEditor(game).set_game(merge=True)

    while True:
        game = build_game(game_id)
        ut.slack.SlackOperator(game).update_vote_stage_lower()
        c1 = len(game.frozen_guessers) == 1
        c2 = game.time_left_to_vote <= 0
        c3 = not game.remaining_potential_voters
        if c1 or c2 or c3:
            game.dict['frozen_voters'] = deepcopy(game.dict['voters'])
            game.dict['vote_stage_over'] = True
            ut.firestore.FirestoreEditor(game).set_game(merge=True)
            game.stage_triggerer.trigger_pre_result_stage()
            logger.info(f'pre_result_stage triggered, game_id={game_id}')
            return make_response('', 200)
        if ut.time.datetime1_minus_datetime2(
                reusable.time.get_now(),
                call_datetime) > game.self_trigger_threshold:
            game.stage_triggerer.trigger_vote_stage()
            logger.info(f'vote_stage self-triggered, game_id={game_id}')
            return make_response('', 200)
        time.sleep(game.refresh_interval)
```

Here, game.self_trigger_threshold = 60s and game.refresh_interval = 9s. The vote_stage function has a timeout of 540s.

The method game.stage_triggerer.trigger_pre_result_stage() publishes a message to a topic "topic_pre_result_stage" which triggers the "pre_result_stage" cloud function.

The method game.stage_triggerer.trigger_vote_stage() publishes a message to a topic "topic_vote_stage" which triggers the "vote_stage" cloud function.

The only inner log i find is:

```
2021-11-06 15:08:49.594 GMT vote_stage rvfnd4wo5nwd 2021-11-06 15:08:49,594 - INFO - start, game_id=20211106_150714&T01LTPERV4Z&C02EKL5PQAX&U01LFAZNKPV&2694551026434.1707796879169.ce017050e1e74e97332c2a04d4b19c08
```

Here is a screenshot (took at 2021-11-07) of the Legacy Logs Viewer showing all the logs of this function execution (with execution_id = rvfnd4wo5nwd):

[image]

Here is a screenshot (took at 2021-11-07) of the Legacy Logs Viewer showing all the logs with level = "Errors" of the vote_stage function:

[image]

As one can see, none is from 2021-11-06.

Comment: How long did you wait before checking for completion?  How were you looking in the logs?  For example, what if the function crashed ... I'd imagine that would show up in unfiltered logs but might not show up in filtered logs.  Maybe look in Cloud Logging directly to see if more can be seen.

Comment: I just add these details to the question.

Comment: How long take the processing? What's the cloud functions timeout

Comment: The processing takes about 70s. The timeout is 540s.

Comment: This could sound like a one off. It could be the service ran out of memory or other resource. More likely, a log just got lost due to some system hiccup. Could you check if some of your current execution IDs still behave as you described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have the bugs anymore. I did the following change: i replaced `publisher.publish(**kwargs)` by
`publisher.publish(**kwargs).result()`
This function is used to trigger a pubsub topic.

As described here https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting : If your function creates asynchronous tasks, it must also explicitly wait for these tasks to complete.

Answer (score 0):

The missing logs entries from Cloud Functions is not something usually expected and could be caused by termination of the process before it reach the phase where the logs are forwarded to Cloud Monitoring. The missing log entry is not typically a concern but could indicate some unbalanced configuration. The premature resource termination can be caused by exhausting some limit. It looks like your function takes significant amount of time.

```
vote_stage oga5hymuzx4p Function execution took 66563 ms, 
finished with status: 'ok'
```

Where default timeout is 1 minute and it can be extended up to 9 as your function says that it has a timeout of 540s.

- https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout

In your setup, the function has the timeout close to the limit and it happens that it consumes most of execution time. So it could be possible that logs would not be captured. What could help is to experiment with Cloud Functions configuration and provide more resources but that could not be sufficient as the root cause is not known here.

The best option I could suggest is to reach out to [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/contact) to properly check for what is going on in the background and to properly understand the traffic characteristics of the function. GCP has a free trial that you can try and support for it is available as well.